# System hangs at boot after making application autostart

Tags: linux, debian, autostart

I developed an application using Qt for Debian-KDE platform. To make application automatically start at boot, I cretae a Desktop Entry file in

```
/home/user_name/.kde/Autostart/
```

This leads to freeze at boot. I realized that it is possibly because of the line in the Desktop Entry:

```
Exec=gksu -u root $DIR/gui.py
```

"gksu -u root" requires root password and as system boots, it is not possible to authenticate the application for user. When I remove "gksu -u root", system boots normally and the application starts. However, application needs root privileges to run properly. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Use `gksudo` instead and allow your user to run this command as root without password in your sudoers file ? `visudo` to edit it.